# How to compile AVR code in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, avr

Why does the following code not work in Arduino?

```
#include<avr/io.h>
void setup()
{
    DDRA = 0xFF;
}
void loop()
{
    PORTA = 0xAA;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTA = 0x55;
    _delay_ms(1000);
}
```

I get the following error.
"DDRA was not declared in this scope."

As I know, arduino uses AVR microcontrollers, so why can't we use AVR code
in arduino boards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User261391 has the first issue with your code. You will then quickly find you also need to include delay.h for the delay to work.

Revised Example:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/delay.h>
void setup()
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;
}
void loop()
{
    PORTB = 0xAA;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB = 0x55;
    _delay_ms(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The normal AVR chips used in Arduinos do not have a port A register, usually it is B/C/D .

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe forget to include some library?

Comment: I included avr/io.h
Forgot to mention in the code.
Now updated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

The thing is that the Arduino type is probably set to Arduino Uno, which has a different DDRA defined(I guess)... You can set the type in

> TOOLS->Board->Arduino Mega 2560

if you only want to compile it and see if the code has no error.